# jQuery - How to show and hide labels and inputs in multiple rows in a table

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table id="tblBranchCoverage" class="hideOnLoad" width="100%">
    <tr class="coverageRow" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <td class="countyCovered" width="115px">
            <label class="branchCountyCovered coverageDisplay">Douglas</label>
            <input type="text" class="edit editBox editCounty" style="display: none; width: 111px;" value="Douglas"><br>
            <input type="submit" class="button edit submitCoverageEdits" style="display: none;" value="Save Changes"><br>
            <input type="submit" class="button edit cancelCoverageEdits" style="display: none;" value="Cancel">
        </td>
        <td class="stateCovered" width="30px">
            <label class="branchStateCovered coverageDisplay">GA</label>
            <input type="text" class="edit editBox editState" style="display: none; width: 22px;" value="GA" max-length="2">
        </td>
        <td class="zipsCovered">
            <label class="branchZipsCovered coverageDisplay">30122, 30133, 30134, 30135, 30154, 30187</label>
            <textarea class="edit editBox editZips" style="display: none;" cols="100">30122, 30133, 30134, 30135, 30154, 30187</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="coverageRow">
        <td class="countyCovered" width="115px">
            <label class="branchCountyCovered coverageDisplay">Forsyth</label>
            <input type="text" class="edit editBox editCounty" style="display: none; width: 111px;" value="Forsyth"><br>
            <input type="submit" class="button edit submitCoverageEdits" style="display: none;" value="Save Changes"><br>
            <input type="submit" class="button edit cancelCoverageEdits" style="display: none;" value="Cancel">
        </td>
        <td class="stateCovered" width="30px">
            <label class="branchStateCovered coverageDisplay">GA</label>
            <input type="text" class="edit editBox editState" style="display: none; width: 22px;" value="GA" max-length="2">
        </td>
        <td class="zipsCovered">
            <label class="branchZipsCovered coverageDisplay">30028, 30040, 30041</label>
            <textarea class="edit editBox editZips" style="display: none;" cols="100">30028, 30040, 30041</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to iterate through the rows of the table, find the row (there will be only one at the most, but it can be that all rows will have the labels displayed and the inputs hidden) that has elements with class "edit" that are set to "display: none". When that row is found, I need to hide the .edit elements and show the labels (which at that time will have the style "display: none" set).

I'm doing this within this context:

```
$('#tblBranchCoverage').on('click', 'tr', function() {
```

So, basically, when the user clicks on a row all other rows in the table will have the .edit elements hidden and the labels shown and in the clicked row edit elements should display and the labels get hidden.

The closest I've gotten to it working is this:

```
    $(this).parent().find('tr td').each(function() {
        $(this).find('.edit').hide();
        $(this).find('.coverageDisplay [style*="display: none"]').show();
    });
    $(this).find('.coverageDisplay').fadeOut(200);
    $(this).find('.edit').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
});
```

Which isn't really "close" at all, since the row that is clicked on gets all of its elements hidden.

I've been messing with this for two hours. I'd really love some help!

Thanks.

**[Edit]**
As requested, here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eventide/KZhhH/).

Comment: Could you please create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qj89m/)?

```
$('#tblBranchCoverage').on('click', 'tr', function() {

  // hide all other .edit's and show all other labels
  $('#tblBranchCoverage tr').not(this).find('.edit').hide();
  $('#tblBranchCoverage tr').not(this).find('label').show();

  // hide this row's label and show this row's edit div
  $('label', this).hide();
  $('.edit', this).show();
});
```

Comment: I originally marked Jeff's answer as the correct one, but when I put it in the context of my actual web page it didn't hide the edit row, as required. Chandu's answer only worked after a row was clicked on a second time. They all worked within the context of the jsFiddle, but this is the only one that works within my web page, so, One Trick, you get the prize! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery's `siblings()` method to get at the other `<tr>` elements: http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

```
$('#tblBranchCoverage tr').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.edit').fadeIn(200);
    $(this).find('label').fadeOut(200);
    $(this).siblings('tr').find('label').show();
    $(this).siblings('tr').find('.edit').hide();
});
```

You might prefer this approach so that clicking on a row that's already in edit mode won't hide and re-fade it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet that works as you mentioned.

```
var $tbl = $('#tblBranchCoverage'),
    $lables = $tbl.find('td .coverageDisplay');
    $editables = $tbl.find('td .edit'),
$tbl.on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $editables.hide();
  $lables.show();
  $this.find('.coverageDisplay').fadeOut(200);
  $this.find('.edit').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
});
```

Here is the link to jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/greenrobo/JsGrx/

Answer (score 0):

Youll also want to disable the onclick trigger for the currently selected row. Here is my implementation for that :

http://jsfiddle.net/cH6Ba/15/

```
editRow() {

    $('#tblBranchCoverage .edit').hide(); // hide all edits. 
    $('#tblBranchCoverage label').show(); // show all labels. 
    $('#tblBranchCoverage tr').on('click', editRow); //rebind all events

    $(this).find('.edit').delay(200).fadeIn(200); // show our inputs
    $(this).find('label').delay(200).fadeOut(200); // hide our labels
    $(this).closest('tr').off('click', editRow); //unbind trigger on current row. 
};

$('#tblBranchCoverage tr').on('click', editRow);
```

Jeff's solutions also accomplishes this pretty cleanly.